Different results with different approaches to a problem about cylinder sigma algebra
Let $R^T$ be the set of all functions from $T$ to $R$. Let $\{x \in R^T : (x_{t_1},...,x_{t_n} \in A\}$ for $t_1,...,t_n \in T$ and $A \in B(R^n)$ be cylinder set and $B(R^T)$ be the smallest sigma algebra containing cylinder sets.
There is a theorem which states that if $C \in B(R^T)$ then there exist countable subset $T_0 \subset T$ such that if $x,y \in R^T$ and $x=y$ on $T_0$ then $x \in C \iff y \in C$.
Problem:
Let $C=\{x : \sup\{\lvert n(x_n-x_{n-1} \rvert\}:n=1,2,...\}<\infty$. Is it true that $C \in B(R^{[0,\infty)})$?
Consider constant function $x=2$ and $y=2$ everywhere but at points $1,3,5,7,...$. Due to the theorem $C \notin B(R^{[0,\infty)})$.
On the other hand $$C=\{x: \exists_{M \in \mathbb{N}} \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}}: n\lvert(x_n-x_{n-1}) \rvert<M\}=\cup_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x : (x_{n-1},x_n) \in \{(x,y):\lvert y-x \rvert <\frac{M}{n}\}\}.$$ Which is countable sum of countable intersection of cylinder sets so should be in $B(R^{[0,\infty)})$.
What is wrong with this?

"Consider constant function $x=2$ and $y=2$ everywhere but at points $1,3,5,7,...$. Due to the theorem $C \notin B(R^{[0,\infty)})$" No. It looks like you take $T_0 = \{1,3,5,7,...\}$ and notice, that this $T_0$ "do not work". But if you take $T_0 = \{1,2,3,4,5,...\}$ in that theorem, you will see that "everything works".
Indeed, if $T_0 = \{1,2,3,4,5,...\}$  and $x=y$ then $(x \in C) \Longleftrightarrow (y \in C)$. And in fact $C \in B(R^{[0,\infty)})$.
So the answer is connected with the next fact: the theorem states that there exists some $T_0$ with good properties and the theorem doesn't  promise us that the set $\{1,3,5,7,...\}$ will have good properties.

Yeah I misread, thank you
